# Can I encapsulate code when extending the video tag using Web component technologies?

Tags: shadow-dom, custom-element

I am trying to extend the video tag using Web Component technologies (HTML templates, Shadow DOM, Custom Elements). I would love to encapsulate my styles and DOM (edited). However, as we can not attach a Shadow DOM to the video tag, I am unsure how to accomplish this goal (or if this goal is even possible with Web Component technologies alone).

For example, I would like to scope all the contents of template (lines 14-230) to the TimeStamp class (which extends the video tag) in my main.js file. https://github.com/chelBot/videoJS/blob/master/index.html

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to upgrade the `<video>` component you can create a class for your own component that will use its own CSS and the class will have all your custom JS.

*Remember that shadowDOM does not encapsulate JavaScript, just the DOM and CSS. The best way to encapsulate your JS is to put it into your own class.*

Your template could be something as simple as this:

```js
const template = `<style>
:host {
  display: inline-block;
  Anything else for the component shell
}
</style>
<video></video>`;
```

You JavaScript would need to take some attributes and the children and pass them through to the `<video>` element. But this should not be difficult.